# Anime where a girl with no powers goes to a magic school

Tags: story-identification, magic, anime

I’m pretty sure the girl just stumbles upon the school randomly. I also remember a character that has the power to make stuffed animals come to life. I think I also remember a scene where the characters are running through a forest being chased by a gigantic bunny or some other animal.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)

Comment: It sounds vaguely like the new animated movie *Mary and the Witch's Flower*, which is based on Mary Stewart's novel *The Little Broomstick*. Maybe the anime was based on the same story? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_and_the_Witch%27s_Flower

Comment: Do you remember anything about books or a library?  Because this sounds like it could be Märchen Mädchen.

Answer (score 4):

Is it the anime series [*Little Witch Academia*](https://myanimelist.net/anime/33489/Little_Witch_Academia_TV)? In it, wannabe witch Kagari "Akko" Atsuko stumbles in to Luna Nova Magical Academy. There are also [two short films](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Witch_Academia#Short_films), [two manga series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Witch_Academia#Manga), and [a video game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Witch_Academia#Video_game) in the franchise.

[image: An image of the characters, along with the name in Japanese ("リトル ウィッチ アカデミア") and English ("Little Witch Academia")]

Comment: @named What is second 'OVA'?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Witch_Academia#Short_films) describes it

Answer (score 2):

Gakuen Alice?

https://gakuenalice.fandom.com/wiki/Gakuen_Alice_Chapter_028

> Mikan goes for a walk after getting the lowest grade on her semester tests. That is when she encounters a group of living stuffed animals carrying a bucket of water to give to their master for his medication. She helps them and meets Kaname Sonō, who happens to be Tsubasa's friend he was speaking of. Kaname and Mikan visit the Special Ability class to surprise everyone that Kaname was temporarily released from the hospital. His alice is revealed to be the alice that brings stuffed animals to life, meaning he is Mr. Bear's creator